# lightning:select component is broken in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

When I use the `lightning:select` component in classic context (with Lightning Out) it works fine. However, when in Lightning Experience context (added as a page element) it causes an 'internal error' without any meaningful message. This is the piece of code which causes the error:

`<lightning:select aura:id="chargeType" value="{!v.chargeType}" label="Charge Type">
    <option value="capture">Capture</option>
    <option value="open">Charge on Due-date</option>
    <option value="auth">Authorize</option>
</lightning:select>`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's why you have this error, but `lightning:select` has a `name` attribute that is required and that you're not setting.
You can have a look to the doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm).